# Mouse-over truncated messages on star wall to see full message

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

Sometimes comments are too long to fit on the star wall, and are truncated with "...":

[image]

It would be nice if holding the mouse over these showed a tooltip or something with the full message text, or if some other way of expanding the message was provided.

The messages can currently be viewed by clicking the timestamp then viewing the whole thing in the transcript. Not difficult, really, but a little cumbersome.

(Unless this feature exists already, and I missed it, in which case: Oops.)